# How to process multiple files using a python script 'from the terminal' and not using another script or loops?

Tags: python, bash, terminal, batch-processing

I have a python file that takes an image and a pdf as input, computes and prints the Levenshtein distance between the OCR and data extracted from pdf.

The image name and pdf name are as follows -
**Image** - 'foo_1.png', 'foo_2.png', etc. (One png per page of pdf)
**pdf** - 'foo.pdf'

**Directory structure**
Dir
|
|__ Images
 |
 |__ foo_1.png
 |__ foo_2.png
|
|__ Documents
 |
 |__ foo.pdf
|
|__myScript.py

I call the script from terminal like `~/Dir$ python myScript.py foo`
The files 'foo_1.png', 'foo_2.png' and 'foo.pdf' are called, processed and the result is printed as follows.

**Current output in terminal** -

> field1 -
>   L Dist - 61 L Ratio - 0.47
>   field2 -
>   L Dist - 54 L Ratio - 0.37

Is there a way to **call the script from terminal** to process several such files in a directory?

**Expected output in terminal** -

> field1 -
>   L Dist - 61 L Ratio - 0.47
>   field2 -
>   L Dist - 54 L Ratio - 0.37
>
> field1 -
>   L Dist - 30 L Ratio - 0.07
>   field2 -
>   L Dist - 84 L Ratio - 0.87

I already have python script to achieve the batch processing. I wanted to know if there is a way to achieve this from terminal by calling only to the '**myScript.py**'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. You can ls the folder and save the output to a file or variable in bash and then iterate over the file/variable and pass the items into python myScript.py some_value

Easiest way would to just do something like this:

```
for file in $(ls); do python myScript.py $file; done
```

Comment: Thanks @markmacher. I already have a script to batch process files, store them in a pandas DataFrame and go forward with other processes. My question is to only understand if there is a way to call a script that processes only one file, on a batch of files, from the terminal with some command like `python myScript.py *.png`

Comment: @AccLok I think your question is a bit off then.  So do i understand correctly that you want to run python myScript.py some_file.png and only this file would be ran with the script? Im confused.

Answer (score -2):

First download the python package with its help we can execute the task.
after downloading launch the application and in terminal open the python normal and text file to check whether the specified file available or not.
after that provide full path of text file and press enter it executed successfully.